# How to draw Multiple line between x1,y,1,y2 using coreplot in ios8?

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, ios8.1

[image]In my app am drawing multiple line using "CPTScatterPlotFieldY" and "CPTScatterPlotFieldX".I can draw line between X vs Y1.

Now i want to draw line between X Vs Y2.How to code in :numberForPlot:" delegate.
I used following code for X vs Y1.

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
     NSDictionary * dic = [self.growthArr objectAtIndex:index];
           // NSLog(@"fieldEnum%lu",(unsigned long)CPTScatterPlotFieldY2);
            switch (fieldEnum) {
                case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:

                    return [dic valueForKey:@"Weeks"];

                    break;
                case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
                    if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weightG1"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Weight"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weightG2"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Wt1"];


                    } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weightG3"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Wt2"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weightG4"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Wt_1"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weightG5"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Wt_2"];
                    }

                    break;
}
```

Red line added on plot space 2 .I don't understand why this is showing slanted.blue plot are x axis vs y1 axis.

but  red plot for x axis and y2axis its showing like this. where am wrong.

Comment: And what didn't work ? Be more specific.

Comment: I don't understand how to draw line between X vs Y2 .X axis is comman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-addPlot:` method always adds plots to the default plot space.

When setting up the plots, use the `-addPlot:toPlotSpace:` method to add the plots to the graph. Specify the "y2" plot space for the plots that should use the secondary scale.

Comment: [graph addPlot:HC3 toPlotSpace:plotSpace2]; and y2.plotSpace = plotSpace2;   how to specify y2 plot space for plot  plz help am very near to final result.

Comment: You got it. `[graph addPlot:HC3 toPlotSpace:plotSpace2];` Just make sure the plot space exists before you call this method.